# How can I split String by two or more new lines without using libraries?

Tags: python, string

I have this String:

```
Hello World.\n
I'm very happy today.\n\n\n\n\n
How are you?\n\n\n
Bye.
```

And I want to split it by two or more new lines without using any libraries.
Output:

```
['Hello World.\n I'm very happy today','How are you?','Bye']
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Do you know how to split a string based on a delimiter?

Comment: what did you try? Did you try to use `for`-loop and count new lines ?

Comment: `[x for x in s.split('\n') if x]` ? Or are there some special requirements?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: `split` is a method of a built-in class, so you're not using any "libraries".  Look up how to use it.

Comment: [split on 2 or more new lines - without libraries](https://pastebin.com/K4r0vAhn) - similar problems I made long ago in C/C++ as student.

Answer (score 0):

Python's base string function `split()` should work here, without the need to import anything:

```py
inp = "Hello World.\nI'm very happy today.\n\n\n\n\nHow are you?\n\n\nBye."
terms = inp.split('\n\n')
print(terms)
```

This prints:

```
["Hello World.\nI'm very happy today.", '', '\nHow are you?', '\nBye.']
```